# Detect edges of screen

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am using following code to drag a rectangular in windows 8 app using c#

```
void Drag_ManipulationDelta(object sender,ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Move the rectangle.   
   dragTranslation.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
   dragTranslation.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y; 
}
```

But when I throw the rectangle it disappears from screen, I want to keep rectangle within the screen, how to detect the edges of screen?

Comment: code source: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387.aspx

Comment: Are you asking how to detect the width & height of your control?

Comment: Use the Window.Current.Bounds property.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant, But i am not sure how to use Window.Current.Bounds

Comment: How to compare Window.Current.Bounds values with the coordinates of Rectangle